# Combine ApexChart horizontal box plot with scatter point, with categories as xaxis

Tags: vuejs3, scatter-plot, boxplot, apexcharts, nuxt3

Trying to plot some data on a box plot and outliers as scatter points in a nuxt3 app.
I have two main issues
Is it possible to combine horizontal box plot with scatter points.
If its not possible with horizontal box plot, how to do the same with vertical box plot with xaxis as categories.
The box plot on its own works but when I introduce the scatter points it stops working.
his is the config for the box.

```
const chartOptions = reactive({
  chart: {
    type: "boxPlot",
    toolbar: {
      show: true,
    },
  },
  title: {
    text: props.name,
    align: "center",
  },
  xaxis: {
    type: "category",
    categories: props.transitions,
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      horizontal: props.horizontal,
      barHeight: "50%",
    },
    boxPlot: {
      colors: {
        upper: tailwindColors.indigo["400"],
        lower: tailwindColors.indigo["100"],
      },
    },
  },
  stroke: {
    colors: [tailwindColors.gray["400"]],
  },
});
```

this is the series object.

```
[
    {
        "type": "boxPlot",
        "data": [
            {
                "x": "cat-1",
                "y": [
                    2.396,
                    2.396,
                    2.43,
                    2.451,
                    2.457
                ]
            },
            {
                "x": "cat-2",
                "y": [
                    1.053,
                    1.072,
                    1.082,
                    1.262,
                    1.32
                ]
            },
            {
                "x": "cat-3",
                "y": [
                    1.019,
                    1.021,
                    1.037,
                    1.045,
                    1.045
                ]
            },
            {
                "x": "cat-4",
                "y": [
                    1.265,
                    1.265,
                    1.271,
                    1.282,
                    1.284
                ]
            },
            {
                "x": "cat-5",
                "y": [
                    1.147,
                    1.164,
                    1.171,
                    1.333,
                    1.386
                ]
            },
            {
                "x": "Idle Time",
                "y": [
                    0.129,
                    0.13,
                    0.134,
                    0.136,
                    0.136
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "scatter",
        "data": [
            [
                "cat-1",
                1
            ],
            [
                "cat-1",
                1.353
            ],
            [
                "cat-1",
                3
            ],
            [
                "cat-2",
                0.02
            ],
            [
                "cat-2",
                3.566
            ],
            [
                "cat-2",
                5
            ],
            [
                "cat-3",
                0.01
            ],
            [
                "cat-3",
                11.121
            ],
            [
                "cat-4",
                0.1
            ],
            [
                "cat-4",
                0.297
            ],
            [
                "cat-4",
                3
            ],
            [
                "cat-4",
                5.142
            ],
            [
                "cat-5",
                4.585
            ],
            [
                "cat-5",
                5
            ],
            [
                "Idle Time",
                0.066
            ],
            [
                "Idle Time",
                3.5
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried different combinations for the scatter points
tried:

1. Array with combination of category and value.
2. Array with combination of number and value.
3. object in this format {x: category, y: value}
   None of them worked. I feel like I am doing something wrong.
   Thank you in advance for your help.